# How to create Multipart Response

Tags: java, spring, httpclient, multipartform-data, jersey-2.0

I am working on restful web services where I want to generate Multipart response in below format:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK  
Server:  
MIME version:  
Content-type:Multipart/form-data  
Content-length:500; boundary=  
--Boundary--

content-type:  
content-Disposition: ;name="abc"  

[content]  
--Boundary--  
content-Disposition: ;name="cba"  

[content]  
--Boundary--
```

This reponse will contains results of queries and wont contain any url.

I have used MimeMultipart:

```
MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
// ...add files to multipart
MimeBodyPart firstPart = new MimeBodyPart();      
imagePart.setContent(Object, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);

    MimeBodyPart secondnPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    jsonPart.setContent(Object, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    multiPart.addBodyPart(firstPart);
    multiPart.addBodyPart(secondPart);
return Response.ok(multipart, "multipart/form-data").build();
```

But that doesn't create in the above format. I am using Spring framework for implementation. Not getting the header.

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart(); /*add files to multipart*/ return Response.ok(multipart, "multipart/form-data").build();

Comment: @jsalonen Do you have any idea? or Can I implement  by using other libraries like HttpClient?

Comment: how do you add those files? Also what kind of format does it produce if its not the desired one?

Comment: @jsalonen I have updated the question. How can I test for my input?

Comment: re: `test for input` I recommend WireShark so you can see exactly what gets sent.  re: `Boundary` Only the last is `--Boundary--` all the earlier ones should be `--Boundary`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I did for Multipart/form-data response in Jersey 2:

```
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataMultiPart;

FormDataMultiPart fdm=new FormDataMultiPart();
fdm.field("abc", Object o1, MediaType.APPLICATION_yourmediatype).field("cba", 
Object o2, MediaType.APPLICATION_yourmediatype);
Response response=Response.ok(fdm, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA).build();
```